# Data Binding to a winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I thought I would give data binding a shot in winforms and created an object datasource for my project using a class. I let the IDE create a dataGridView and controls for the datasource by dragging them onto the form.

What I would like to do now is set the datasource for the whole form to a collection of these classes. So the controls are 'auto magically' populated. I did this once before but don't have access to the code right now. My google searches only turn up binding to controls.

I'm pretty sure it had something to do the the BindingContext of the form but again, no help from google.

Comment: help came from google: http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html

Comment: This is where I first learned object [Data Binding](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=7)

Comment: Probably, you are talking about the `BindingSource` (drag n drop onto a form) which you hook on with a `custom object` [a class in your project which exposes some public properties] and this bindingsource is then fed into other controls via the `DataBindings > Advanced Properties` of individual controls and `then each control can be programmed to respond to this bindingsource based on an event (which is again selectable in the Advanced Properties window of the control databindings)`?

Comment: Reinuiz: Thanks, I saw that, but it's just binding to controls.

Comment: There is no auto-magic, you need to set binding context to form and binding sources of each control to appropriate data.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out again. When you drag and drop these controls on your form, the IDE creates a datasource for them. It then 'auto magically' assigns all your controls datasources to this datasource.

private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource conversion4GLBindingSource;

So all I have to do is:

this.conversion4GLBindingSource.DataSource = Conversion4GL.History;

in the form_load event and all my stuff works... auto magically! Pretty cool really. It's really cool when your class inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged and you can see your fields change as you type.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Read my earlier comments. Also, what do you meant by `IDE creates a datasource` ? Which component are you talking about here ?

Comment: In the 'form name'.Designer.cs. When you drag the datasource onto your form from the 'data sources' window the IDE generates a whole bunch of code. It actually create either a datagridview control with a column for each property or a group of textboxes, labels and or comboboxes (you can select which by clicking on the data source). It also generates the aforementioned data source, which I forgot about.

Comment: Also, to make use of your INotifyPropertyChanged event on your non-grid controls, go into Data Bindings > Advanced and set theupdate mode to OnPropertyChanged.